# "non-algebraically closed" or "not algebraically closed"?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

I am working on a problem, where it happens that fields, that do not have the property of being algebraically closed, cover the important cases. Now I thought quite a long time about the question of how to call such fields. Should it be "non-algebraically closed fields" or "not algebraically closed fields"?

On the one hand, in general, if we have any adjective $A$, we negate it by non-$A$. For instance, the contrary of a "soft question" should be a "non-soft question". "Not soft question" would be grammatically false.
On the other hand "non-algebraically closed" looks unlogical since one could think that the "non" only has to do with the "algebraically" and is independent from the "closed".

But now again if I say "Let $K$ be a not algebraically closed field." this sounds very unnatural to me.

As I am not a native speaker in English, I would be very thankful for any of your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sadly, there is no canonical terminology for this. Algebraically open has a different definition. As long as you are consistent and clear with your terminology, I'm sure your proposals would be accepted.

Comment: You could use a relative clause: "a field that is not algebraically closed"

Comment: From my experience, people usually say "non-algebraically closed", using it as an adjective. Also in French "non algébriquement clos". I'm not sure about the spellings though.